# VirtualBox can't get back to main screen to select different VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Ubuntu 18.04.5, GUI Xfce 4.12 (by Xubuntu)
VirtualBox 6.1.22 r144080 (Qt5.9.5)

Somehow I got logged in full screen (within VirtualBox Manager) and am now stuck on a single VM.  I can get to its settings, also in full screen, control it, etc.  But I can't get back to home where I can select a VM.

[image: VirtualBox Manager Screen]

I have Googled this issue and can't find anything that will get me back to the main manager home page.

Hope someone has been here before and figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left panel of the VirtualBox Manager window has been resized to zero width.

With your mouse cursor, reach the left border of the VirtualBox Manager window. Mind reaching the border from inside the window, so you don't resize the whole window horizontally. The cursor will change to resize the left panel.

The resizing is crude. You might move the cursor almost to the center of the window for it to resize.

Reference from the [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=98152).

Comment: Apparently I don't have the reputation to mark this as answered or upvote it, but it fixed it for me.  Thanks, Psedro